# Another slices of the universe than space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spacetime, quantum-entanglement, observable-universe

We observe a particular kind of "slices" of our universe: the slice that is called "space" (in the special sense of our 3 dimensional physical space).

Are other kinds of slices in any way researched? (references, please, personally me now more want popular rather than scientific articles)

For example, what's about a slice of the universe such that "points" (probably in a mathematical space where the same physical space points for different quantum fields are different, because, for example, an electron and a quark could be in the same place, but one entangled with another electron and the another not entangled with another quark) that are quantum entangled with each other are identified?

I assume that this way we get kinda another laws of physics (despite of being based on the same "base" like SM and GR). For example, is it possible (that is not falsified) that in these other laws there is time, life, intelligent beings, technology, etc.? Can that world's intelligent beings influence our world or vice versa? Is anything known about this?

Comment: Nothing known about that

Comment: Are you asking about string theory?

Comment: @nick012000 I am asking about anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> ... is it possible (that is not falsified) that in these other laws there is time, life, intelligent beings, technology, etc.?

Many, many things are possible, in the sense that they have not been shown to be impossible. Some of these things, such as [Russell’s teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot), are very difficult to disprove. Science (and, in particular, physics) deals with what can be verified by experiment and observation. Everything else is speculation.

Comment: You don't understand my question: I ask whether this is mathematically possible in existing physical models.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard model of elementary particle physics is already very good at explaining and predicting the outcome of experiments. Metaphorically speaking, its nature is like an extremely complicated gearbox where many gears mutually engage with each other in a pretty unique way in order to yield specific transmission ratios on multiple driveshafts.

If you appear on this stage and say "how about doing it in a completely different way, just... without gears", you are responsible for achieving the same gear ratios at the outputs, and due to the mutual dependencies of the gears it might turn out to be a very difficult task, although, a-priori, there is of course nothing wrong about trying to do things differently and better. Your idea might seem brilliant to you at first sight, but it might very well be, that you will end up messing around with a lot of detail problems when trying to achieve the same things as the standard model.

In a sense, you are trying to reinvent the wheel, albeit a very complicated one.

Comment: My question is not abou experiments but about a different thought experiment in SM.

Comment: @porton: that may be the reason why your question has been closed, because some people are very sensitive to the smell of weed in purely thought-experiment-oriented approaches to a natural science like physics